# What if L1 reject state commit from starknet L2?

Tags: blockchain, starknet, layer-2

According to the description of the transaction lifecycle in the [official website documentation](https://docs.starknet.io/documentation/architecture_and_concepts/Network_Architecture/transaction-life-cycle/), there are four finality states for a transaction: `NOT_RECEIVED`, `RECEIVED`, `ACCEPTED_ON_L2`, and `ACCEPTED_ON_L1`.

My question is, when a transaction is in the `ACCEPTED_ON_L2` state and the proof is submitted to L1 for verification, if the verification fails, will the transaction remain in the `ACCEPTED_ON_L2` state indefinitely? Will the transaction be rolled back on L2? If not, how is the consistency between L1 and L2 ensured?

I expect a clear description of how StarkNet or other L2 networks (whether ZK or OP) handle the situation where L1 rejects L2 commit.